# How do I style the scrollbars of a GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt

What is the proper way to override the style of the GWT DataGrid scrollbars? To be more specific, I want to have a constant opacity of 1.0 instead of the default transition effect.

There seems to be no way to pass a custom resource to the CustomScrollPanel used in DataGrid, and by default CustomScrollPanel sets the default transparant resources for its scrollbars.

I already tried the following:

- Call setHorizontalScrollbar/setVerticalScrollbar to set new scrollbars. Because I cannot reach the CustomScrollPanel attribute (tableDataScroller) in DataGrid this isn't working.
- Add the NativeHorizontalScrollbar.Style and NativeVerticalScrollbar.Style to my CssResource and override nativeHorizontalScrollbarStyle and nativeVerticalScrollbarStyle in css. Without a way to pass in the resource this doesn't seem to be working.
- Override the browser scrollbar style using the ::-webkit-scrollbar selector and friends. While this works for other scrollbars in my UI, and for some of the DataGrid scrollbar properties the opacity transition effect remains in place.

Comment: Have you tried important! with ::-webkit-scrollbar?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Ah yes, the !important 'sledgehammer' seems to work. Thanks, I can use this as a workaround for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is generally the way to go (or at least how the `CssResource` injection should be used to override widget styles). Unfortunately, as you guessed, `DataGrid` does not expose its inner `CustomScrollPanel` (see the relevant [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6865)).

Extend `DataGrid` to expose its inner `CustomScrollPanel` as suggested in the issue. That way you can replace the scroll bars styles (and/or the scroll bars themselves) with whatever you want (using `setHorizontalScrollbar()`/`setVerticalScrollbar()`).

```
public class EnhancedDataGrid extends DataGrid {

  /**
   * Expose the inner CustomScrollPanel.
   */
  public CustomScrollPanel getScrollPanel() {
    HeaderPanel headerPanel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
    return (CustomScrollPanel) headerPanel.getContentWidget();
  }
}
```

Or you can decide to let it implement `HasScrolling` to expose all the methods of the `ScrollPanel`'s scrolling contract (that will simply delegate to the `getScrollPanel()` method).

Comment: Thanks, also for the pointer to the specific GWT issue. This reminds me that next time I can explicitly search the GWT issue list, as it didn't show up in my google searches.